# I get the error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Whenever I try to turn the data I fetched from the server, I get this error:

```
Unexpected end of JSON input.
```

I tried using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` as well, but nothing seems to be working.

Server code:

```js
app.get('/details', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(Character)
  next()
})
```

Client Code:

```js
fetch('/details')
  .then(res => res.json())
```

Response Headers:

- `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
- `X-Powered-By: Express`
- `Content-Type: application/json; charset=ut-8`
- `Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2020 12:24:24`
- `GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0`

Comment: You're going to have to inspect the actual JSON response content.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The browser developer tools have a "Network" tab that will let you look at the HTTP response body.

Comment: It says that response data is not avaliable

Comment: Well that's probably the problem then. Are you sure the HTTP response did not result in an error?

Comment: If I dont use "res.json()", I dont get any errors

Comment: Of course, because you're not asking the JSON parser to parse anything.

Comment: then What can I do about this?

Comment: I have no idea; I don't know what your server is doing, and you didn't post the HTTP response headers.

Comment: I updated the postso you can see the response headers

Comment: That shows that there's no error. You'll have to debug your server code and find out why the response is empty.

Comment: What does your json/`Character` look like ?

Comment: I found the problem nevermind